# How to access the data from return JSON from webservice in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i have a return json data which returns the webservice 
The structure of webservice is like that:

```
jsonp1332655154667({"products": [{"uid": "37",
"samsid": "hjk",
"name": "Science%20Essentials%2010%20AC%20edn",
"shortname": "scienceessentials10",
"description": "Science%20Essentials%2010%20ACE%20is%20the%20fourth%20in%20a%20series%20of%20four%20books%20designed%20for%20the%20National%20Curriculum.%20",
"generated": "3/25/2012%205:59:19%20AM",
"Description": "Science%20Essentials%2010%20ACE%20is%20the%20fourth%20in%20a%20series%20of%20four%20books%20designed%20for%20the%20National%20Curriculum.%20",
"PublishingCompany": "Macmillan%20Australia",
"Service": "OneStopScience",
"Service": "OneStopDigital",
"Icon": "http://curriculumplatform.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/icons/brain48.png",
"Country": "Australia",
"Shortname": "scienceessentials10",
"MarketingSite": "http%3a%2f%2fwww.macmillan.com.au%2fsecondary%2fonix%2fall%2f6F597241EFC0E43DCA257791001CAFC0%3fopen%26div%3dSecondary%26cat%3dScience%253EAustralian%252BCurriculum%26template%3ddomSecondary%26ed%3dsite%2fseced31.nsf",
"Skin": "OneStopScience%20Green"},
"tag":"s_science"'
"tag":"s_maths"'
"tag":"s_arts",
{"uid": "5",}]})
```

I have three "tag" elements. but when we access the products.tag it gives always last element like:s_arts.
Is there any way to find out all the elements eg:s_science,s_maths,s_arts.
please help.

Comment: try `console.log(products.tag)` and tell us what happens

Comment: Isn't that invalid JSON?

Comment: it Gives tag:s_arts last element of tag.

Comment: Either you are missing comma after first two tags or this json is invalid

Comment: well, good luck with that web service, because getting the other tags ain't happenin'

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid json, your tag should be:

```
...,
"tag": ["s_science", "s_maths", "s_arts" ],
...
```

Then product.tag would be an array that you could access successfully

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure it's invalid per se, but it can only take one, and I've found that it always takes the last one defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple keys in the same object, you're going to get undefined behaviour. Only one will be preserved, and since pairs are not ordered, you can't guarantee which you'll get.

In short: the webservice is returning you faulty data. If multiple tags are expected, the service should return an array of values in the tag attribute:

```
...
"tag":["s_science", "s_maths", "s_arts"],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the tags as an array:

```
jsonp1332655154667({"products": [{"uid": "37",
"samsid": "hjk",
"name": "Science%20Essentials%2010%20AC%20edn",
"shortname": "scienceessentials10",
"description": "Science%20Essentials%2010%20ACE%20is%20the%20fourth%20in%20a%20series%20of%20four%20books%20designed%20for%20the%20National%20Curriculum.%20",
"generated": "3/25/2012%205:59:19%20AM",
"Description": "Science%20Essentials%2010%20ACE%20is%20the%20fourth%20in%20a%20series%20of%20four%20books%20designed%20for%20the%20National%20Curriculum.%20",
"PublishingCompany": "Macmillan%20Australia",
"Service": "OneStopScience",
"Service": "OneStopDigital",
"Icon": "http://curriculumplatform.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/icons/brain48.png",
"Country": "Australia",
"Shortname": "scienceessentials10",
"MarketingSite": "http%3a%2f%2fwww.macmillan.com.au%2fsecondary%2fonix%2fall%2f6F597241EFC0E43DCA257791001CAFC0%3fopen%26div%3dSecondary%26cat%3dScience%253EAustralian%252BCurriculum%26template%3ddomSecondary%26ed%3dsite%2fseced31.nsf",
"Skin": "OneStopScience%20Green"},
"tags": [
    "s_science"'
    "s_maths"'
    "s_arts"
],
{"uid": "5",}]})
```

Then you reference them as `data.tags[0], data.tags[1], data.tags[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

if your response is in this format

```
YourResponse = {
    "products" : [
                   {"uid" :"5", ......., "whtever":"someval"},
                   {"uid" :"6", ......., "whtever":"someval1"}
                 ]

};
```

you can use this

```
$(YourResponse).each(
function(objName, objValue) {
    console.log(objName); // wil get object name like uid, whtever
    console.log(objValue); // wil get object's value

});
```

so to get Tags you will have to take Tuan's suggestion; send them in array